# Regex: Remove Commas within quotes

Tags: json, regex, csv, apache-nifi

I'm using NiFi and I have a series of JSONs that look like this:

```json
{
  "url": "RETURNED URL",
  "repository_url": "RETURNED URL",
  "labels_url": "RETURNED URL",
  "comments_url": "RETURNED URL",
  "events_url": "RETURNED URL",
  "html_url": "RETURNED URL",
  "id": "RETURNED_ID",
  "node_id": "RETURNED id",
  "number": 10,
    ...
  "author_association": "xxxx",
  "active_lock_reason": null,
  "body": "text text text, text text, text text text, text, text text",
  "performed_via_github_app": null
}
```

My focus is on the "body" attribute. Because I'm merging them into one giant JSON to convert into a csv, I need the commas within the "body" text to go away (to help with possible NLP later down the road as well). I know I can just use the replace text, but capturing the commas themselves is the part I'm struggling with. So far I have the following:

```
((?<="body"\s:\s").*(?=",))
```

Every guide I look at, though, doesn't match the commas within the quotes. Any suggestions?

Comment: what if body contains `\"` ? i'd use script..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```java
(\G(?!^)|\"body\"\s*:\s*\")([^\",]*),
```

In case there are escape sequences in the string use

```java
(\G(?!^)|\"body\"\s*:\s*\")([^\",\\]*(?:\\.[^\",\\]*)*),
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0CDAKb/1) (and [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/0CDAKb/2)), replace with `$1$2`.

*Details*:

- `(\G(?!^)|\"body\"\s*:\s*\")` - Group 1: end of the previous match or `"body"`, zero or more whitespaces, `:`, zero or more whitespaces
- `([^\",]*)` - Group 2 (`$2`): any zero or more chars other than `"` and `,`
- `,` - a comma (to be removed/replaced).