# Regex translation to python acceptable format

Tags: python, java, json, regex

I've found this regex that seems to work for Java but not python.
found it here: [Regex: Remove Commas within quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69831183/regex-remove-commas-within-quotes)

```py
r"""(\G(?!^)|\"body\"\s*:\s*\")([^\",]*),"""
```

I am very inexperienced with building my own regexes and need help translating it to python acceptable format. I know the \G is the problem as it doesnt exist in python(?)

I want to use it to replace commas in the "body" key in my JSON file but I get:

bad escape \G at position 1

Comment: What does "seems to work" mean?  What does "work" mean, for that matter? If you have a JSON string, _parse it_, then update the now-native data structure based on what you need using all the APIs available in your programming language for working with its own data structures, and then if you need it turned back into JSON, do that.

Comment: it would help to show [1] where you are stuck and [2] what output you expect to achieve....    https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Python does not have an "end of previous match" meta-character (which is what `\G` is for Java regexes). It would be helpful to know what exactly you need to parse with this, because it's quite possible there's a simpler or alternative regex that will do.

Comment: Don't edit your post to say "I will add all the details soon (eta 8h)". Just edit it when you're able to edit it. If it gets closed in the mean time, post a new question with all the actual details in it.

Comment: You'll have to settle for a call back solution as the `\G` is only available in Pythons `import regex` module. Using `import re` the sub callback would replace all the commas in the string. I haven't checked your regex but it seems dubious anyway.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, I would argue that last bit of your advice might result in question ban. It always better to edit your current question, and submit it to reopening process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The proper solution

Use the JSON module to parse the JSON, modify the resulting object, then stringify again:

```py
import json

json_str = '{"body": "a, b", "foo": "bar", "baz": "foo"}'
json_obj = json.loads(json_str)
def replace_commas_body(obj):
    if type(obj) == list:
        for elem in list:
            replace_commas_body(elem)
    elif type(obj) == dict:
        if "body" in obj:
            obj["body"] = obj["body"].replace(",", ";")
        for elem in obj.values():
            replace_commas_body(elem)
replace_commas_body(json_obj)
print(json.dumps(json_obj))
```

This prints `{"body": "a; b", "foo": "bar", "baz": "foo"}` as expected.

#### The RegEx solution

Just for the kicks of it, I also wrote a RegEx solution. This works fine because regular expressions suffice to tokenize JSON, and the changes required here can pretty much be done at a token level.

The (slim) advantage of this solution is that it preserves the "style" of the JSON (spacing, ordering of keys, number formatting used, characters escaped, etc.).

The disadvantage is that it is less readable / more difficult to maintain and much less flexible: It doesn't know the context. Changing this to e.g. apply only to certain objects which also have certain other keys or are inside certain other objects would not be possible.

For the sake of simplicity, I have decided to not handle Unicode escape sequences of the form `\uXXXX` at all, although these ASCII codepoints may theoretically be encoded that way; typically it won't be, and it's trivial to fix the solution to handle them properly by using `(?:<character>|\\u<ASCII code>)` for each ASCII character within the string (the characters `b`, `o`, `d`, `y` and the comma).

Here goes the RegEx: [`(\"body\"\s*:\s*\")((?:[^\"\\]|\\.)*?)(\")`](https://regex101.com/r/ZH9AKa/1)

Explanation:

- `(\"body\"\s*:\s*\")`: Capture the `"body" : "` part to preserve it; allow for arbitrary spacing, just like JSON.
- `((?:[^\"\\]|\\.)*?)`: Capture the body of the string. Allow zero or more arbitrary characters except for backslashes or string quotes, which need to to be escaped.
- `(\")`: Preserve the closing quote of the string. We could have hardcoded this in the `lambda` just as well, but this is cleaner if you want(ed) to extend this in the future.

and here's the corresponding Python, with a small test case:

```py
import re

json_str = '{"body": "a, b", "foo": "bar", "baz": "foo"}'
print(re.sub(r"(\"body\"\s*:\s*\")((?:[^\"\\]|\\.)*?)(\")",
    lambda m: m.group(1) + m.group(2).replace(",", ";") + m.group(3),
    json_str))
```

---

In my examples, I'm replacing commas (`,`) with semicolons (`;`). You link a question about *removing* commas but mention *replacing* commas (with what?) in your question so I was unsure.

Answer (score -2):

What you could do is first capture the data within the *body* value, and then parse on the comma.

The pattern would be,

```
\"body\"\s*:\s*\"(.+)\",
```

> *"... I am very inexperienced with building my own regexes ..."*

It's quite simple; it just seems complex.

I recommend reading the *Wikipedia* article, as it outlines the entire syntax.
*[Wikipedia – Regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)*.

Additionally there are several books; *[O'Reilly Media](https://www.oreilly.com/)* and *[Packt Publishing](https://www.packtpub.com/)* both have some good ones.
*[O'Reilly Media – Mastering Regular Expressions](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/mastering-regular-expressions/0596528124/)*.
*[Packt Publishing – Mastering Python Regular Expressions](https://www.packtpub.com/product/mastering-python-regular-expressions/9781783283156)*.

Here is an example in *Python*.
I'm using the *[re.match](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?#re.match)* function to utilize the pattern.
And, the *[str.split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)* function to generate a list of values.

```py
string = '"body": "abc, def, ghi",'
value = re.match(r'\"body\"\s*:\s*\"(.+)\",', string)
value = value.group(1)
strings = value.split(', ')
```

Output

```
['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
```

Comment: This RegEx is not correct. The `(.+)` is too greedy, possibly consuming `"`'s. Test with a e.g. `"body": "a", "morestuff": "a,b,c", "evenmore": "test"` - the match will be `"body": "a", "morestuff": "a,b,c",`.

Comment: @Luatic, write an answer.

Comment: sure, see below.